# Using IPython with breakpoint()

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

How to do a set up that when I call `breakpoint()`, IPython shell is invoked instead pdb?

Currently, Python uses pdb, which has no completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done through setting the `sys.breakpointhook`, which is called when you set a `breakpoint()`:

```py
import sys
import IPython
sys.breakpointhook = IPython.embed
```

Comment: To turn off a banner at every breakpoint `sys.breakpointhook = functools.partial( IPython.embed, display_banner=False )` worked, `ipython --no-banner` didn't.

Comment: And how to enter into ipdb?

Comment: @Run perhaps you'll prefer `pdb++`: it's entered automatically whenever you call `breakpoint()`